# Odoo: Download binary field content as text file

Tags: python-2.7, download, odoo-8

i am working on an addons to export invoices in a semi-colon separated file. I have created a wizard to choose invoices one wants to export and i am able to write data in file located in the my_module/data/invoices.txt. Now i want to download this file, i used the saveas method in the web addon but i end up with a 404 error (i have a binary field (`txt_file`) in the wizard to store the file's content as base64 encoded data).
Here is the code i am using:

```
@api.multi
def export(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    if self.invoice_ids:
        lines = []
        for line in self.invoice_ids:
            str_line = ''
            str_line += str(line.partner_id.name) + ';'
            str_line += str(line.number) + ';'
            str_line += str(line.origin) + ';'
            str_line += str(line.date_invoice) + ';'
            str_line += str(line.date_due) + ';'
            str_line += line.account_id.name + ';'
            str_line += line.journal_id.name + ';'
            str_line += str(line.amount_untaxed) + ';'
            str_line += str(line.amount_total) + ';'
            str_line = str_line.encode('utf-8')
            lines.append(str_line)
        import os.path

        my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        path = os.path.join(my_path, "../data/invoices.txt")

        file = open(path, 'w+')
        if file:
            output = ''
            for line in lines:
                output += line + '\n'
            self.txt_file = base64.b64encode(output)

            file.write(base64.b64decode(self.txt_file))
            wizard = self.env['export_invoice.wizard'].with_context({'active_id': self.id}).create({})
            # I have found this on the web
            return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
                'url': '/web/binary/saveas?model=export_invoice.wizard&field=txt_file&id=%s&filename_field=invoices.txt' % (
                wizard.id),
                'target': 'self',
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem might be in the line

```
wizard = self.env['export_invoice.wizard'].with_context({'active_id': self.id}).create({})
```

If the idea is to add the specified context to the wizard without otherwise modifying it, do not add `.create`, which called with an empty dict will create and return an empty wizard record, which does not have contents in the file field, hence the 404.

```
wizard = self.env['export_invoice.wizard'].with_context({'active_id': self.id})
```

On a side note, the `filename_field` GET parameter expects a model field name that contains the file name, not the actual file name. This should not break the download, but the download file name will be generated, not the one specified.

Comment: Thanks @dgeorgiev, i've managed to download the file but i've got another problem. The '\n' is not interpreted, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean that the text editor you open the file with does not show the new line properly? Is it possible that the editor expects Windows style eols?

Comment: Yes @dgeorgiev, that's exactly what happened. I don't know maybe, as you said, the editor expects Windows style eols.